# Is there any way to disable [Esc] from being "Back" in Android Studio's Android emulator?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I use IdeaVim and have gotten in the habit of tapping Esc frequently to get out of insert mode, etc. I also use Esc to go from the Terminal window back to the Editor. So basically I tap Esc a lot.

I've recently starting doing some android dev in Android Studio.

One thing that I keep doing by accident is pressing Esc while I'm focused on the emulator window.

When this happens, it simulates a "Back" action on the emulated Android device.

Is there any way to change this keybind? It's pretty annoying because I'm currently working on something where Back just closes the app and goes to the home screen, so every time I press Esc I have to re-open the app. And since I'm using Flutter, this seems to mean I need to re-run my `main.dart`.

Comment: Go to Android Studio Settings > keymap > type in search "back" and see which item is associated with the Esc shortkey

Comment: I did use the key-based search in keymaps, unfortunately it doesn't look like it's listed there. I figure it might be something built in to the emulator.